# How to keep CPU running while closing screen?

Tags: android, cpu, android-powermanager

There is a time-consuming task (a Thread) in Fragment. It works fine. But, when I close the screen, I see the CPU not work so that the task cannot work fine.

I have use `PowerManager` in Activity, but not work Fragment too.
Also add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "CPUKeepRunning");
    wakeLock.acquire();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (wakeLock != null && wakeLock.isHeld()) {
        wakeLock.release();
        wakeLock = null;
    }
}
```

I have saw the CPU
[image]

Comment: avoid to use long-running operations in fragments or activity. try to replace your thread to service, and acquire wakeLock before start operation and release wright after end your long-running operation

Comment: why service not thread ?

Comment: you can use thread inside service. Service creates to perform long-running operations and minimize wide range of troubles that may occurs with using long running threads in activity or fragment.  You can read a lot about services here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your code through a Service, if you're running it in an Activity it will stop once the activity goes in the background. Use Services instead.

http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: I use  `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and  `IntentService` .It works fine!       [http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/scheduling/wakelock.html](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/scheduling/wakelock.html)